# How do I connect Google Sheets as a database to a Kotlin app?

Tags: kotlin, google-sheets

What I plan to achieve is be able to pull data from the sheets.

Name
I.D
Image URL
Website URL

and populate a text view, image view and webview.

Comment: Maybe you can use the [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java)?

Comment: Tried it, editing the url like this https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1yswxocjQbUuOulKCUIxHv2IfoGSeG90S0K8rA31iBBI/od6/public/values?alt=json, doesn't work anymore

Comment: @CodexGuy, you need to use a new version of Sheets API (v4). Checkout [migration guide](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/migration#v4-api_5).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The endpoint mentioned `http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/<feed>/<key>/<worksheet>/public/<...>?alt=json` was provided by an older Google API called [GData (Google Data Protocol)](https://developers.google.com/gdata/samples/spreadsheet_sample).
- That API however is being deprecated. Users of GData API (Spreadsheet endpoint) must migrate to [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api).
- To fetch the values of the Sheets file from your Kotlin app, I’d recommend using the method [spreadsheets.values/get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get).

Comment: Documentation was lengthy and a bit tricky to implement "token" but it worked.